# How To Create A chart Like Trading View LineChart In Flutter?

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-layout, syncfusion, tradingview-api

Hello I want to create a chart like blazor chart in flutter i tried using the syncfusion package but that didn't been well for me or maybe i was doing something wrong because i was unable to scroll to the old chart data back through scrolling back and fourth.
Also I'm a beginner and i don't have such idea

Here's What I'm trying to accomplish using flutter, Please Guide Me!

I want To Create Something Like This

[image]

Comment: I'm the author of this package: https://pub.dev/packages/interactive_chart it's open source, might be useful for you to see how it's made?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fl_chart`](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) package. It's highly configurable.

Here's one chart modified from [the example](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/tree/master/example) and a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to make it scrollable.

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff232d37),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: LineChartSample2(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LineChartSample2 extends StatelessWidget {
  LineChartSample2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Color> gradientColors = [
    Colors.white,
    Colors.black38,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 2000,
        height: 400,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 18.0, left: 12.0, top: 24, bottom: 12),
          child: LineChart(
            mainData(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xff68737d),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16,
    );
    Widget text = const Text('', style: style);

    final step = data.length ~/ 4;
    if (value.toInt() % step == 0) {
      final index = value.toInt() ~/ step;
      text = Text('0:${(index * 5).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}', style: style);
    }

    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 8.0,
      child: text,
    );
  }

  Widget leftTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
    const style = TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xff67727d),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 15,
    );
    String text = const {
          1: '10K',
          3: '30K',
          5: '50K',
          7: '70K',
          9: '90K',
        }[value.toInt()] ??
        '';
    return Text(text, style: style, textAlign: TextAlign.left);
  }

  LineChartData mainData() {
    return LineChartData(
      gridData: FlGridData(
        show: false,
      ),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        show: true,
        rightTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        topTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
        ),
        bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            reservedSize: 30,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: bottomTitleWidgets,
          ),
        ),
        leftTitles: AxisTitles(
          sideTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            interval: 1,
            getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets,
            reservedSize: 42,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      borderData: FlBorderData(
          show: false,
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xff37434d), width: 1)),
      minX: 0,
      maxX: data.length - 1,
      minY: 0,
      maxY: 10,
      lineBarsData: [
        LineChartBarData(
          spots: [
            for (final entry in data.entries)
              FlSpot(entry.key.toDouble(), entry.value.toDouble())
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          barWidth: 2,
          isStrokeCapRound: true,
          dotData: FlDotData(
            show: false,
          ),
          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
            show: true,
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: gradientColors
                  .map((color) => color.withOpacity(0.3))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

final data = [
  3.45,
  2.14,
  1.88,
  2.02,
  2.25,
  2.20,
  2.18,
  2.49,
  2.87,
  3.06,
  3.00,
  2.35,
  2.08,
  2.22,
  2.24,
  2.43,
  2.14,
  2.16,
  2.16,
  1.85,
  2.02,
  1.90,
  2.12,
  1.71,
  1.85,
  1.77,
  1.79,
  2.14,
  2.25,
  2.29,
  2.31,
  2.79,
  2.54,
  2.72,
  2.37,
  2.35,
  2.41,
  2.66,
  2.79,
  3.04,
  3.58,
  4.29,
  3.99,
  4.42,
  5.05,
  5.01,
  5.51,
  8.90,
  8.16,
  5.61,
  5.23,
  5.19,
  4.19,
  3.72,
  3.10,
  2.97,
  2.18,
  2.45,
  2.33,
  2.29,
  2.31,
  2.31,
  3.02,
  3.43,
  3.50,
  3.25,
  2.99,
  3.08,
  3.54,
  4.12,
  4.04,
  4.74,
  5.42,
  7.70,
  5.92,
  5.25,
  5.80,
  5.82,
  5.03,
  4.99,
  4.62,
  4.62,
  4.46,
  6.12,
  6.13,
  5.37,
  5.38,
  5.70,
  6.33,
  6.26,
  5.92,
  5.41,
  5.15,
  6.34,
  6.16,
  6.58,
  6.15,
  6.13,
  6.95,
  7.16,
  6.46,
  7.17,
  7.62,
  9.52,
  1.75,
  3.41,
  0.30,
  3.05,
  8.68,
  7.54,
  6.88,
  7.16,
  6.25,
  6.20,
  6.16,
  7.13,
  4.90,
  5.84,
  7.41,
  6.73,
  6.54,
  8,
  7.11,
  7.59,
  7.63,
  7.34,
  6.21,
  6.21,
  6.08,
  6.74,
  7.09,
  7.11,
  7.99,
  8.53,
  9.41,
  0.17,
  1.26,
  2.68,
  1.08,
  8.25,
  7.66,
  6.74,
  6.67,
  5.82,
  5.24,
  4.51,
  3.95,
  3.5,
  3.83,
  3.79,
  3.37,
  3.14,
  2.99,
  4.00,
  3.66,
  5.34,
  5.83,
  5.32,
  4.29,
  4.03,
  4.13,
  4.79,
  4.62,
  4.32,
  3.89,
  3.43,
  3.70,
  4.25,
  4.49,
  4.08,
  3.97,
  4.24,
  4.30,
  4.54,
  4.41,
  4.05,
  3.89,
  3.56,
  3.24,
  3.16,
  2.66,
  2.50,
  2.16,
  1.94,
  2.43,
  2.45,
  2.95,
  2.83,
  2.85,
  3.31,
  3.54,
  3.33,
  3.33,
  3.33,
  3.81,
  4.16,
  4.04,
  3.83,
  3.62,
  3.43,
  3.62,
  3.68,
  3.64,
  4.24,
  4.70,
  6,
  4.90,
  4.66,
  4.58,
  4.58,
  4.04,
  3.91,
  3.91,
  3.77,
  4.12,
  3.47,
  2.99,
  2.87,
  2.83,
  2.60,
  2.85,
  2.77,
  2.83,
  2.77,
  2.66,
  2.33,
  2.08,
  1.92,
  2.27,
  1.98,
  1.72,
  1.91,
  1.91,
  2.58,
  2.81,
  2.81,
  2.99,
  2.97,
  2.54,
  3.58,
  3.29,
  2.85,
  2.87,
  3.10,
  3.14,
  2.97,
  2.97,
  2.89,
  2.97,
  2.87,
  3.00,
  2.81,
  3.87,
  2.66,
  2.68,
  2.79,
  2.79,
  2.97,
  2.83,
  2.95,
  3,
  3.27,
  4.08,
  4.04,
  3.10,
  2.68,
  2.95,
  2.64,
  2.64,
  2.39,
  2.37,
  2.22,
  2.56,
  2.33,
  2.64,
  2.22,
  2.02,
  1.90,
  1.79,
  1.73,
  1.75,
  1.62,
  1.77,
  2.29,
].asMap();
```

Comment: Sir I've Tried This One But I'm Having A Problem because when data gets too much in chart it shrinks rather than moving forward ad not shrinking the graph and also i want the data to add the scrolling functionality so that when i scroll back i can see the old graph ploted as well how can i do that using this fl_chart

Comment: You can wrap it around a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) and set its width to a fixed size depending on the data amount. This way you're able to scroll it horizontally and the data doesn't shrink.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please take a look.

Comment: SIr Thank You Very Much And Also i'll follow the guidance you provided of minimal and reproductible example

Comment: Hello Sir Can You Help Me Once Again Can You provide me some resource where i can learn how to create trading chart and also as you've noticed it has a ROC indicator which changes to the position once some amount is bid

Comment: That indicator is present on the right where the chart bar ends in the above picture i've shared

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way with `fl_chart`. You'd need to customize the widget, [its source is open](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart). Or create a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and build yourself the line above it.

Comment: Thanks Sir I am using stack right now to do it so

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the chart in any direction by enabling the ZoomPanBehavior.enablePanning property. In addition, ZoomPanBehavior.zoomMode can be used to control the zooming and panning directions. For more details about zooming and panning, check out our User Guide documentation https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/zoom-pan.

Code snippet:

```dart
zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
  enableMouseWheelZooming: true,
  zoomMode: ZoomMode.x,
  enablePanning: true,
  enablePinching: true
),
```

You can refer to infinite scrolling from this sb sample - https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/infinite-scrolling